# Creating a new entity object when an entity information changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 3 Entities: **Asset, User, Log**

Relationships are:

- An Asset can have many Users, a **User** can have many Assets. So this is a Many-to-Many Relationship.
- A **Log** is can have only 1 Asset, an **Asset** can have many **logs**. So this is a One to Many relationship with the Asset as the owning side.

So the scenarios are like this:

- If I assign an asset to the user on the application side, I should
  get a **new** Log like this (log_id, asset_id, Asset has been
  assigned to user_fullname)
- If I assign a user to the asset on the
  application side, I should get a **new** Log like this (log_id,
  asset_id, Asset has been assigned to user_fullname)
- If I remove an asset to the user on the application side, I should
  get a **new** Log like this (log_id, asset_id, Asset has been
  remove from user_fullname)
- If I remove a user to the asset on the
  application side, I should get a **new** Log like this (log_id,
  asset_id, Asset has been remove from user_fullname)

I tried it like this on the asset entity:

```
    public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->users[] = $user;
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist(new Log($this,
                    "Asset has been added to" . $user->getFullname()
                    ,$this->getUser()));
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    return $this;
}
```

Which gives me an error that the EM is not found, I did some research and found that this is bad practice.

So I tried this instead:

```
$oldAsset = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Asset')->findOneById($asset->getId());

        if ($assign_form->isSubmitted() && $assign_form->isValid()) {


            foreach($asset->getUsers() as $user)
                if(!$oldAsset->getUsers()->contains($user))
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist(new Log($asset,
                        "Asset has been assigned to " . $user->getFullname()
                        ,$this->getUser()));

            foreach($oldAsset->getUsers() as $user)
                if(!$asset->getUsers()->contains($user))
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist(new Log($asset,
                        "Asset has been removed from " . $user->getFullname()
                        ,$this->getUser()));

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('asset_show', array('id' => $asset->getId()));
        }
```

Which doesn't work cause even before I manually flush it, it "updates" the entity from the database so there is not difference between the old asset and the new asset. Strangely, the edit doesn't push thru anyway once there is an error before the whole method finishes.

I know I am missing something here, maybe there is a way that I don't know yet that would make this possibe.

Comment: Akira, What exactly your functional requirement ? At first look it look like you want to store log when something add/update into user or assets? In that case you can user doctrine events. that will separate the code as well as not affect on your current form code.

Comment: I want to create a log and ofcourse store it when change in asset assignment is made.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved with an event listener ([Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), [Doctrine doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#events)):

**Acme\Listener\UserListener.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Listener;


use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Acme\Entity;

class UserListener {

    /**
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function postUpdate(Entity\User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event) {

        $em = $event->getEntityManager();

        $log = new Entity\Log(...);

        // ...

        $em->persist($log);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Register the listener as a service, tagged with `doctrine.event_listener`:

**services.yml:**

```
services:
    # ...

    Acme\EventListener\UserListener:
        arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener }
```

Now, whenever an operation is flushed that changed a `User` object which is mananged by the entity manager, the `postUpdate` method of your listener should be invoked.

For this next bit I am assuming that you configured `User` to be the owning side in the relation with `Asset`.

If you set up your entities correctly (meaning that you synchronously update the inverse side when you change a relation, more information on which can be found in the [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-and-inverse-side-on-a-manytomany-association) and in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916)), the listener should not only be called if you assign/remove an asset to/from a user, but also if you assign/remove a user to/from an asset.